# Edditing AutoRepeatRate value below 10ms in regedit does not do anything

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-registry

I have a bit of a strange problem, and I would like to ask for some advice.

I want to lower the keyboard *repeat rate* and *repeat delay* beyond what's normally allowed in the control panel by editing registry values instead. However, editing "*AutoRepeat**Rate***" doesn't produce any effect past a certain point. I included a screenshot of my registry values for "Keyboard response" as a reference.
[regedit settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29LLB.png)

I watched a number of tutorial videos on youtube and read some articles on this website on how to do this, and everyone says exactly the same thing:

1. Set all the values besides *Flags*, *AutoRepeat**Delay*** and *AutoRepeat**Rate*** to 0.
2. Set *Flags* to 59
3. Set *AutoRepeat**Delay*** and *AutoRepeat**Rate*** to preferred values.

That being said, lowering "*AutoRepeat**Rate***" to any value below 10ms still gives the same repeat rate as 10ms. I have no issues with *AutoRepeat**Delay*** settings, as it responds to what values I enter and changing *AutoRepeat**Rate*** values to anything above 10ms does make a difference, so it seems to me that I'm doing the right thing but it just doesn't work.

Some more information that I think is related to the issue I'm having:

I managed to make all this stuff work around 2 weeks ago without any issues, however, I didn't like the idea of me manually editing the registry, so I reset everything to how it was and instead opted for a utility named "keyrate" ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171326/how-can-i-increase-the-key-repeat-rate-beyond-the-oss-limit)) that let me edit the *repeat rate* and *repeat delay* values through it. However, I recently noticed that "keyrate" utility didn't lower the repetition rate as much as it should, so I tried to go back to manual registry editing, but it stopped working as well.

When I was doing my own research on the issue, I found out that the "keyrate" utility that I used doesn't lower the *repeat rate* to values under 10ms, which is exactly the problem I'm having with the registry now as well. This makes me believe, that using the utility is what somehow caused me to have this issue now.

Here is the source code for the utility:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL parseDword(const char* in, DWORD* out)
{
   char* end;
   long result = strtol(in, &end, 10);
   BOOL success = (errno == 0 && end != in);
   if (success)
   {
       *out = result;
   }
   return success;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FILTERKEYS keys = { sizeof(FILTERKEYS) };

   if (argc == 1)
   {
      puts ("No parameters given: disabling.");
   }
   else if (argc != 3)
   {
      puts ("Usage: keyrate <delay ms> <repeat ms>\nCall with no parameters to disable.");
      return 0;
   }
   else if (parseDword(argv[1], &keys.iDelayMSec) 
         && parseDword(argv[2], &keys.iRepeatMSec))
   {
      printf("Setting keyrate: delay: %d, rate: %d\n", (int) keys.iDelayMSec, (int) keys.iRepeatMSec);
      keys.dwFlags = FKF_FILTERKEYSON|FKF_AVAILABLE;
   }

   if (!SystemParametersInfo (SPI_SETFILTERKEYS, 0, (LPVOID) &keys, 0))
   {
      fprintf (stderr, "System call failed.\nUnable to set keyrate.");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to read it, therefore I don't know how could I possibly reverse the changes it has done to my PC. For this reason, I would like to ask for help from someone who does know what is going on.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help me out.

Comment: Part of what the program does is change accessibility settings. Settings - Ease Of Access - Keyboard - Filter Keys.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, it does enable the filter keys, however, I have to do the same thing if I edit the registry manually. By setting the Flags value to 59 in "Keyboard response" registry section, I enable the filter keys, so from my understanding, enabling filter keys is a must if you want to decrease keyboard's repeat delay beyond the control panel's limits. For this reason, I'm not sure where should I go from here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The program doesn't edit the registry but sets the settings in memory when it is run.  Therefore is is either running at logon and shouldn't **or** isn't running at logon and should be.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa

Comment: I had to use the cmd command to change my repeat rate and repeat delay every time I started up my PC, however, I do not understand why I can't set my repeat rate to below 10 anymore, sorry if it is very obvious, but I'm completely in a dark.

Comment: Windows doesn't handle this. It merely tell the 8042 keyboard controller integrated circuit  (which is still emulated on current PCs) what settings to use. It table of settings are here https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~huang/cs318/fall18/project/specs/kbd/scancodes-11.html

Comment: so If I understand what you are saying correctly, I need to find some kind of emulator online that can access 8042 controller and change values through it?